# How can I run a .php file located in my site's root folder?

Tags: php, htaccess

I am trying to convert some data from custom post types into custom tables in my Wordpress database. I have written a PHP program to do this. It requires that Wordpress be loaded so I can use some of Wordpress's database access methods ($wpdb).
I have placed the conversion file in my site's root directory where index.php resides, but when I try and run it

```
http://my-site.dev/convert.php/
```

I get a 404 page not found error. How can I configure Wordpress or my server (I'm using Desktop Server locally for development) to run this program?

Comment: Sorry. The file is not in wp-contents but rather the site's root directory.

Comment: Have you looked at WP CLI? PHP files shouldn't have slashes on the end like that, its trying to load a folder named convert.php, but that's not how URLs work

Comment: @RussellEubanks please edit your question/title with that information.

Comment: @TomJNowell On _most_ Apache servers, this would actually be a perfectly valid request. The trailing slash (on an existing PHP file) is simply seen as additional _pathname information_ (`PATH_INFO`) and `convert.php` would be loaded just fine (providing it exists). However, if `AcceptPathInfo Off` is set in the server config (or `.htaccess` file) then this will indeed trigger a 404 - but this is not the default behaviour for PHP handlers. But maybe this is what's happening here? (`/convert.html/` on the other hand would trigger a 404 by default because the core handler rejects path info.)

Answer (score 1):

Installing a plugin had modified my .htaccess file. When I restored to the saved original, I was able to run PHP scripts just fine. Thanks to Denver Wordpress Meetup group for suggestions.