# How run a non-WordPress PHP Program on a WordPress site?

Tags: php

I have a question similar to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274786/how-can-i-run-a-php-file-located-in-my-sites-root-folder):

I have created a small PHP program that I want to call as a rest web service to return some data from custom MySQL tables.

I can put it anywhere, but I've tried the root folder (public_html), a folder I creatd called custom, and the cgi-bin folder.

For the first two, I get 404 not found.  For the CGI-BIN it looks like it redirects to my home page.

I've set it with CHMOD to 755 (and the custom folder as well).

My .htaccess looks like this.  I think maybe it needs to change somehow?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't use the WP REST API and `$wpdb` calls to fetch the data?  I'm not sure what WP knowledge could be helpful here, this looks like a generic hosting issue that requires Apache htaccess knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I was mislead by this... I didn't read the code thoroughly that I cloned.  It sets a 404 if the SQL fails.  Duh!  I also discovered a file called /custom/error_log that I think is going to help debug that.

```
// die if SQL statement failed
if (!$result) {
  http_response_code(404);
  die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move Wordpress from root folder into subdirectory and create a `.htaccess` file in root folder, and put this content inside (just change example.com and my_subdir):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L]
```

That's all :)

Comment: Thanks, about to try it. Is my_subdir where I put my PHP program, or where I moved WordPress?

Comment: Assuming my_subdir is wp, where I copied everything.  Home page works, custom PHP still gives 404, and index.php (home page) works, but all other word press pages getting 404.  E.g. The requested URL /wp/aboutcontact/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Plus I don't want to see /wp/ in the my URL or have existing pages change.

Comment: Couldn't I just add some line like this to handle the one PHP file: 
RewriteRule ^checkforms\.php$ custom/checkforms.php [R=301,L] 
(Tried, but still getting 404).